# fingerprint no detected and rfid dell e5570

Tags: dell, 16.10, fingerprint-reader

i can't see my device fingerprint i have installed fingerprint-gui and fprint_demo but and nothing work.

```
Hardware path         Peripheral       Class          Description
=================================================================
                                       system         Latitude E5570 (06DF)
/0                                     bus            05JCVC
/0/0                                   memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/42                                  memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/43                                  memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/44                                  memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/45                                  memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/46                                  processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/47                                  memory         8GiB Mémoire Système
/0/47/0                                memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchrone 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/47/1                                memory         DIMMProject-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2016-09-03 00:48+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent <Unknown>Language-T
/0/100                                 bridge         Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                               display        HD Graphics 520
/0/100/4                               generic        Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14                              bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0            usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1          scsi2           storage        USB  device
/0/100/14/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sdb        disk           500GB Elements
/0/100/14/0/1/0.0.0/1  /dev/sdb1       volume         232GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/14/0/1/0.0.0/2  /dev/sdb2       volume         232GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/14/0/2                          multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/0/3          scsi4           storage        External
/0/100/14/0/3/0.0.0    /dev/sdd        disk           500GB External
/0/100/14/0/3/0.0.0/1  /dev/sdd1       volume         465GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/14/0/4                          input          2.4G Keyboard Mouse
/0/100/14/0/7                          generic        5880
/0/100/14/0/8                          communication  Interface sans fil Bluetooth
/0/100/14/1            usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                            generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
/0/100/16                              communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/16.3                            communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17                              storage        82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
/0/100/1c                              bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0                            display        Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
/0/100/1c.4                            bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c.4/0          wlp2s0          network        Wireless 8260
/0/100/1d                              bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d/0                            generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1f                              bridge         Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                            memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                            multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                            bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/100/1f.6            enp0s31f6       network        Ethernet Connection I219-LM
/0/1                   scsi0           storage        
/0/1/0.0.0             /dev/sda        disk           500GB ST500LM021-1KJ15
/0/1/0.0.0/1           /dev/sda1       volume         499MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2           /dev/sda2       volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3           /dev/sda3       volume         305GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4           /dev/sda4       volume         460MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/5           /dev/sda5       volume         9446MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/6           /dev/sda6       volume         19GiB Volume EXT4
/0/1/0.0.0/7           /dev/sda7       volume         127GiB Volume EXT4
/0/1/0.0.0/8           /dev/sda8       volume         3905MiB Linux swap volume
/1                                     power          DELL HK6DV6B


Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5834 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 13fd:0840 Initio Corporation INIC-1618L SATA
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:28b8 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 1840:13fd  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

Linux ships 4.8.0-41-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:27:17 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev 81)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)



msg FingerPrint Devices : No Devices Found!

Msg Fprint_demo : No devices found.
```

Thanks for your help,
p.s: i don't speak english very well sorry

Answer (score 1):

I have a dell latitude too and I still use it on job.

I had found information about hardware driver before brought it.

I will show you information about fingerprint reader.

**Answer:**

The fingerprint reader of dell is `0a5c:5834`, for now, this device is not supported in linux.

[Reference from archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Latitude_7480)

Hope it helps :)